# "Expected a bytes-like object, str found" with struct.unpack('f', b"".join(map(chr, bytes)))[0] on python3 - but working on python2

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, byte, i2c

First of all, thanks for spending your time on this issue.

Arduino and the RaspberryPi are connected via i2c.

I have the following code on the Arduino:

```
void sendData(){
  #define FLOATS_SENT 4
  #define dhtAPin1 A8
  float data[FLOATS_SENT];
  <attribution from variables to data[0-4]>
  Wire.write((byte*) &data, FLOATS_SENT*sizeof(float));
  delay(2000);
}
```

and the following on python2.* on the RaspberryPi:

```
def get_float(data, index):
    bytes = data[4*index:(index+1)*4]
    return struct.unpack('f', b"".join(map(chr, bytes)))[0]
```

If / when I switch to python3, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to convert string object to bytes via `bytes()` call. And making variable with name *bytes* is not good.

Comment: @0andriy can you expand on the bytes()?
Changing 'bytes' to 'bytesValues' or something.